# Dynamically Limit Download/Upload Speeds of a Application based on Schedule?

Tags: windows, bandwidth, throttling

I've tried a number of solutions like NetLimiter and/or NetBalancer for this, however I've not yet found a complete solution after a few days of Googling. Does anybody know of a way to achieve something similar to the uTorrent Bandwidth scheduler, but on a program that does not natively support bandwidth throttling in the system.

Basically I just need a solution to limit the download speed available to an application based on the time of day.

Answer (score 0):

At the network level you can handle this with an application aware firewall - I've used Sonicwall firewalls in the past to do this with their app control feature. The device gives you the capability to apply a complex ruleset to traffic based on the application signature. Possible operations include block, allow, rate limit, reserve bandwidth and allow no more than x percentage - and there are time of day policy options too. They're pretty foolproof when implemented well and most major vendors have one with similar capabilities - Cisco, Fortinet etc.